# How can I get the right output in the array

Tags: javascript

I need to make an array of [0, 1, 2] when I have the number 3 in the parameter. What's wrong?

```js
const array = [0];
const increment = (num) => {
  if (num > 0) {
    increment(num - 1);
    array.push(num);
  }
  return;
};
console.log(array);
increment(3);
```

Comment: console.log(array) after the increment funciton....Before increment()....array ofc ...not changed at  all..

Comment: And the problem is? Check the array after the `increment(3)` call and adjust your logic accordingly.

Comment: "_What's wrong?_" You log the value of `array` before you're calling `increment(3)`.

Comment: Are you aware that you're calling `increment` recursive ?

Comment: @0stone0 seems like the intention here. I agree it's strange but seems like it's expected.

Comment: Seems like it's expected due to misunderstanding about scopes/function calls.

Comment: I suspect it may be that `array` is a `const` - I was under the impression that you can't manipulate a constant at runtime. Also you're calling increment after outputting the value

Comment: @AndrewCorrigan OP isn't changing the content of `array` (a reference to an array) itself. OP adds elements to the array pointed to by the reference in `array`.

Comment: @Andreas ahhh, just a case of the syntax being counterintuitive for this particular part of javascript then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed in the comment your code almost works you just put `console.log` before calling the function.

```js
const array = [0];
const increment = (num) => {
  if (num > 0) {
    increment(num - 1);
    array.push(num);
  }
  return;
};

increment(3);

console.log(array);
```

Shortest solution with [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

```js
const makeArray = length => Array.from({ length }, (_, i) => i);

console.log(makeArray(3));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
const array = [];
const increment = (num) => {
  if (num > 0) {
    increment(num - 1);
    array.push(num-1);
  }
  return;
};
increment(3);
console.log(array);
```

Comment: I'd suggest `array.push(num-1)` - the existing code would also push the 3

Comment: @Andreas Totally missed that. Thank you for pointing out